# MySQL: Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'

Tags: mysql, corrupt

I did **mysqldump --all-databases** and then had removed MySQL 5.5 from my RD Linux and then installed MySQL 5.1.73 
After that I did import of all databases to new server, but my replication server is not started because there is a problem: on main server after running command **mysql_upgrade** I have an error:

```
    Repairing tables
performance_schema.cond_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_current
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_history
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_history_long
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_instance
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_summary_by_thread_by_event_name
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.events_waits_summary_global_by_event_name
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.file_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.file_summary_by_event_name
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.file_summary_by_instance
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.mutex_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.performance_timers
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.rwlock_instances
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.setup_consumers
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.setup_instruments
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.setup_timers
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
performance_schema.threads
Error    : Unknown table engine 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
error    : Corrupt
Running 'mysql_fix_privilege_tables'...
ERROR 29 (HY000) at line 349: File '/var/log/general.log' not found (Errcode: 13                                                                              )
FATAL ERROR: Upgrade failed
```

I could not find solution for resolve this problem and I hope you will show me the way.

Answer (score 1):

Droped PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA on main server, did mysqldump again, import to replication server, started - ok